# Need help understanding line of code where a method accepts a list as an input parameter. Where is the list created?

Tags: apex, trigger

With reference to the line of code (method createContact) below I am wondering where  List candidateFromTrigger is created? This doesn’t seem to follow the create new list syntax

`public void createContact(List<Candidate_c> candidateFromTrigger)`

Is this statement (below) not required somewhere in the code to create the new List candidateFromTrigger

E.g `List<candidate_c> candidateFromTrigger = new List <candidate_c>();` (I was expecting this kind of stament in the code. I am new to apex)

Goal of the code:

Access method from trigger by passing trigger.new to createContact

A.createContact(trigger.new)

Answer (score 2):

Parameters are initialized from the caller. Consider this trivial example:

```
public Integer add(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Where is "a" and "b" initialized? From wherever the function is called. For example:

```
Integer c = add(5, 10); // c is 15
Integer d = 7;
Integer e = 8;
Integer f = add(d, e); // f is 15
Integer g;
Integer h = add(d, g); // NullPointerException here: g has a null value
```

For triggers, Trigger.new is automatically defined for most cases (except for delete events). It is automatically a list of whatever type of trigger is being called. For example, given `trigger X on Account`, Trigger.new is `List<Account>`. Inside classes, Trigger.new is either null, if you're not in a trigger context, or `List<SObject>` if you're currently in a trigger context.

Comment: Thanks!! You explained this very clearly with your example. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

Trigger.new is the List.  It is a [trigger context variable](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm) that is implicitly available, i.e., it isn't declared anywhere.

Trigger.new is defined as:

> **new**
>   Returns a list of the new versions of the sObject records.
>   Note that this sObject list is only available in insert and update triggers, and the records can only be modified in before triggers.

`public void createContact(List<Candidate_c> candidateFromTrigger)` is a method in which the candidateFromTrigger is a *parameter* defined as a `List<Candidate__c>`.  The method createContact is invoked with the code `A.createContact(Trigger.new)`. The Trigger.new is the *argument* to the method and it is actually a `List<Candidate__c>`.

Comment: Thx for your response. Is candidateFromTrigger also a list which gets the values passed by trigger.new? If yes then why dont we need to declare candidateFromTrigger as a list following normal list creating syntax? Like this: List<candidate_c> candidateFromTrigger = new List <candidate_c>()

Comment: Sure @ThinkFirst! Glad it is clear now! :)